Is there a way to log NFS-server access?
Running an NFSv4 server and wondering if there is a way to log who accessed what. So far my search has yielded nothing useful. rpcdebug shows which clients mounted an exported share, but beyond that there doesn't seem to be any way to log who accessed, wrote to or deleted a file. Let alone with what credentials or from what host.
From a security point of view this lack of an audit trail is a rather big pita.
